# How to use MapStruct for immutable value class by AutoValue (for Android)

Tags: android, immutability, mapstruct, auto-value

I cannot figure out how to use mapstruct 1.3 with Google's @AutoValue. I'm trying to do it on Android, but I doubt that is related to my issues. Are there any documentation on this or examples? I've posted in the [maptruct issues](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1755) regarding lack of documentation.

AutoValue builds an immutable bean, and the builder is created via a method I supply, MyDto.builder(), which returns new AutoValue_MyDto.Builder()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I have updated examples here, for others to see how it plays together.

https://github.com/abeade/mapstruct-test

and my fork

https://github.com/arberg/mapstruct-test

Builders just works out of the box, no special annotation, besides @Mapping. But there seem to be many limitations, and I ran into many of them. It also seems to just work on Android.